# Changing a combo box's ListItem Text without changing its Value

Tags: c#, asp.net, lambda, combobox, listitem

My customer has asked me to add descriptive text into a combo box's drop down list.  I have that part working properly, but the data does not load properly back into the combo box.  I determined that this is because when the descriptive text is set on the `ListItem.Text` property, this propagates to the `ListItem.Value`.  But I don't want the `Value` to change.

My code:

```
    public static List<ListItem> MakeDescriptiveList()
    {
        List<ListItem> items = new List<ListItem>();
        items.Add(new ListItem(string.Empty));
        for (double i = 1.0; i > -1E-9; i -= 0.05) //Roundoff error discovered!
        {
            string value = i.ToString("0.0#");
            items.Add(new ListItem(value));
        }
        items.Find(x => x.Value == "1.0").Text = "1.0\t Foo foo foo";
        items.Find(x => x.Value == "0.9").Text = "0.9\t Bar bar bar";
        items.Find(x => x.Value == "0.8").Text = "0.8\t Baz baz baz";
        ///intermediate items skipped
        items.Find(x => x.Value == "0.0").Text = "0.0\t FAIL";
        return items;
```

On loading data, the code attempts to set `ComboBox1.SelectedValue = value`, where `value` is "1.0" when converted to a string.  But this fails as neither `Text` nor `Value` match.

What's a better way to set up my descriptive text in the combo box, without changing the values of the selections?

(My long term intent, beyond the current release's backlog, is to move all this into the database.  Then I can just set `Text = db.Text` followed by `Value = db.Value` and all will work as I want.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line `items.Add(new ListItem(value))` sets the `Text` of the new `ListItem`.  As `Value` is null, querying `Value` returns `Text`.

I solved this by explicitly setting `Value` in the constructor:  `items.Add(new ListItem(value, value))`.  Then changing `Text` correctly did not affect `Value`.